# Did I find a counterexample to the inference rule $\frac{X, \beta \vDash \alpha}{X, \exists x \beta \vDash \alpha}$ ($x$ not free in $X$, $\alpha$)?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The inference rule
$$
\frac{X, \beta \vDash \alpha}{X, \exists x \beta \vDash \alpha} \qquad \text{($x$ is not free in $X$ and $\alpha$)}
$$
is on p. 79 of *A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (Third Edition) by Wolfgang Rautenberg. Let $\mathcal{M} = (\mathcal{A}, w)$ be a model, let its structure be $\mathcal{A} = (\{0^\mathcal{A}, 1^\mathcal{A}\}, P^\mathcal{A})$, where $P^\mathcal{A} = \{0^\mathcal{A}\}$. Let $X = \varnothing$ for the sake of simplicity, $\beta = P(x)$, $\alpha = \exists x(x \neq x)$ and $w(x) = 1^\mathcal{A}$. Then clearly $\mathcal{M} \nvDash \beta$, $\mathcal{M} \nvDash \alpha$ and $\mathcal{M} \models \exists x \beta$, since there exists $a \in \{0^\mathcal{A}, 1^\mathcal{A}\}$ so that $\mathcal{M}^{a}_{x} \models \beta$ ($a = 0^\mathcal{A}$). (Note: the notation $\mathcal{M}^a_x$ denotes the model $\mathcal{M}$ with $w$ changed at $x$, so that $w(x) = a$).

This seems to be a counterexample to the above inference rule. I really don't see where my reasoning is wrong, I would appreciate some help.

P.S. Here's my metalogical reasoning why the above is a counterexample. We can interpret the inference rule as $(p \to q) \to (p' \to q)$. The inference rule claims that for appropriate $p$, $q$ and $p'$, this propositional formula is a tautology. But it isn't, since it is false in the case $v(p) = 0$, $v(q) = 0$ and $v(p') = 1$, which I constructed.

Comment: How is this a counterexample? A false premise (the first row) can lead to a true inferred sentence (the second row), there's no contradiction in that.

Comment: @lisyarus Did you read my P.S. (which I just added via edit)? Everything I wrote here relies on my metalogical translation of the inference rule into a propositional formula. If my metalogical reasoning is faulty, please, correct me.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich But $X$ is not the domain of my model. $X$ is some set of first-order formulas. The domain of my model $\mathcal{M}$ is indeed non-empty, it's $\{0^{\mathcal{A}},1^{\mathcal{A}} \}$.

Comment: sorry..........

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No problem, sir! Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Btw no, inference rules  do not correspond to tautologies. For example $\frac{p(x)}{\forall x p(x)}$ is a valid inference rule, but $p(x)\to\forall x p(x)$ is certainly not a tautology.

Comment: Probably less important, but it seems likely you're confused about the definition of  "tautology". For example, $\forall x p(x)\to p(x)$ is a valid formula, a theorem, but it is **not** a tautology. (This comes up because of your assertion that inference rules correspond to tautologies; if we're using the word carefully that's obviously nonsense, since a tautology can't possibly know anything about quantifiers. It would be less ridiculous, although still wrong, to say inference rules correspond to valid formulas...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for the insight. I guess that in the case of $\frac{X \models \varphi}{X \models \forall x \varphi}$ ($x$ is free in $X$) the key element is the definition of logical consequence in FOL. Let's say that $X \models \varphi$ and that $\mathcal{M} \models X$. Then $\mathcal{M}^a_x \models \varphi$ for all $a \in A$, since $x$ is free in $X$. Hence, $\mathcal{M} \models \forall x \varphi$. Therefore, $X \models \forall x \varphi$. We see that the interpretation of $\models$ and the fraction line as implication is crucial here. So propositional logic is a guide.

Answer (score 2):

Please, re-read the definition of *model*, page 62:

> A model $\mathcal M$ is a pair $(\mathcal A, w)$ consisting of an $L$-structure $\mathcal A$ **and** a valuation $w: \text {Var} → A$ ...

and that of *consequence*, page 64:

> Further, let $\mathcal A \vDash \varphi$ if $(\mathcal A, w) \vDash \varphi$ for all $w: \text {Var} → A$.

You are saying that:

$$
\frac{P(x) \vDash \exists x (x \ne x)}{\exists x P(x) \vDash \exists x (x \ne x)}
$$

but $P(x)$ has an occurrence of the free variable $x$.

Thus $\mathcal M' \nvDash P(x)$ because with valuation $w'(x)=0$ we have that $P(x)$ is satisfied in $\mathcal M' = (\mathcal A, w')$.

---

*Details are needed*...

Page 62: the satisfiability relation $\vDash$ between models $\mathcal M = (\mathcal A, w)$ and formulas $\varphi$ ... We read $\mathcal M \vDash \varphi$ as ..., or $\mathcal M$ is a model for $\varphi$. Sometimes $\mathcal A \vDash \varphi [w]$ is written instead of $\mathcal M \vDash \varphi$.

Page 64: A formula or set of formulas in $L$ is termed satisfiable if it has a model. $\varphi$ is called *logically valid*, or a tautology, in short, $\vDash \varphi$, if $\mathcal M \vDash \varphi$ for every model $\mathcal M$.

But what means "every model $\mathcal M$"? It means every *pair* $(\mathcal A, w)$.

Thus, when we say: "let $X \vDash \varphi$ if **every model** $\mathcal M$ of $X$ also satisfies the formula $\varphi$", we have to check every pair $(\mathcal A,w)$.

Applying this machinery to the case $P(x) \vDash \bot$ we have that it does not hold, because $\bot$ is always False while the formula $P(x)$ is satisfiable in a model $\mathcal M' = (\mathcal A,w')$ where $\mathcal A$ is defined as above (your example) and $w'(x)=0$.

In general, and "atom" $P(x)$ cannot be neither a tautology nor a contradiction (like an atom $P$ in propositional logic).

Comment: "but $P(x)$ has an occurrence of the free variable $x$."

That doesn't seem to violate anything in the rules. I set $X = \varnothing$ and $\beta = P(x)$. The rule only demands that $x$ be free in $X$ and $\alpha$, not in $\beta$.

"Thus $\mathcal{M}' \nvDash P(x)$ because with valuation $w′(x)=0$ we have that $P(x)$ is satisfied in $\mathcal{M}' = (\mathcal{A}, w')$"

I truly apologise if I'm misunderstanding something, but it seems to me that you are saying that $P(x)$ is satisfied and not satisfied in $\mathcal{M}'$? Did you maybe add an $'$ to $\mathcal{M}$ accidentally at one place?

Comment: Also, how do you make paragraphs in comments?

Comment: Also, what you cited is not the definition of consequence. It's the definition of the satisfaction relation in a structure. If my memory didn't betray me, the definition of a consequence in FOL is: $X \models \varphi$ iff for all models $\mathcal{M}$, if $\mathcal{M} \models \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in X$ then $\mathcal{M} \models \varphi$. (I checked in the book and the definition of consequence is immediately after the portion you cited.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you stated the inference rule incorrectly. The side condition should be that $x$ is *not* free in $X$ and $\alpha$. I checked your reference, and the book by Rautenberg states the rule correctly.

Ok, but that correction is orthogonal from your question. Did you find a counterexample to this sound inference rule? No, of course not. Your mistake is in your interpretation of the meaning of the rule.

Recall that $T\models \varphi$ means "for all structures $M$ (given together with an interpretation of the free variables in $T$ and $\varphi$), if $M\models T$, then $M\models \varphi$".

So the semantic meaning of the inference rule$$
\frac{X, \beta \vDash \alpha}{X, \exists x \beta \vDash \alpha}
$$
is: Suppose that for all structures $M$ (given together with an interpretation of the free variables), if $M\models X$ and $M\models \beta$, then $M\models \alpha$. Then for all structures $M$ (given together with an interpretation of the free variables), if $M\models X$ and $M\models \exists x\beta$, then $M\models \alpha$.

Note that the quantification over all structures occurs both in the antecedent and the consequent! This is quite different from the following condition, which I think was your interpretation: For all structures $M$ (given together with an interpretation of the free variables), suppose that if $M\models X$ and $M\models \beta$, then $M\models \alpha$; then if $M\models X$ and $M\models \exists x\beta$, then $M\models \alpha$.

Your supposed counterexample does not work, because it's not the case that $X,\beta\models \alpha$. Indeed, it's easy to find a structure and a value of the free variable $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true but $\exists x\, (x\neq x)$ is false.